# Unable to invoke optional function on a protocol when inheriting from a generic class

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

If a subclass implements an optional function, calling the function on the protocol works as expected. Namely it'll call the child's method even though it's not implemented in the parent.

When we introduce generics to the parent class, this behavior stops working.

Here's a playground showing the problem...

```
import UIKit

@objc
protocol MyProtocol {
  @objc optional func foo()
}

// MARK: - Works

class Parent: MyProtocol { }
class Child: Parent {
  func foo() { print("Child.foo()") }
}

(Child() as MyProtocol).foo?()
// ✅ Outputs `Child.foo()`



// MARK: - Broken

class BrokenParent<T>: MyProtocol { }
class BrokenChild: BrokenParent<String> {
  func foo() { print("BrokenChild.foo()") }
}

(BrokenChild() as MyProtocol).foo?()
// ❌ Bug: does not output anything
```

Why does this happen, and what workarounds are there to fix it?

Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the conformance of `class BrokenParent<T>` to `MyProtocol` should have been outright disallowed. If you tried to mark `BrokenParent<T>` as `@objc`, you would get the error: `generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' because they are not directly visible from Objective-C`. Thus IDK why a protocol conformance to an `@objc` protocol would be allowed, either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it happens, but I suspect that the `@objc protocol` causes the Objective-C runtime to be used to dispatch the event, and Swift has some behind the scenes code to make the simple case work (and omitted the more complicated inheritance+generic case). I could totally be wrong on this though, and would love to learn the real reason.

Here are two snippets that can be added to the same playground that show the workarounds available, namely (1) implementing the method in the parent class, or (2) using the `@objc` keyword on the method name.

```
// MARK: - Fixed 1

class FixedParent1<T>: MyProtocol {
  open func foo() {}
}
class FixedChild1: FixedParent1<String> {
  override func foo() { print("FixedChild1.foo()") }
}

(FixedChild1() as MyProtocol).foo?()
// ✅ Outputs `FixedChild1.foo()`



// MARK: - Fixed 2

class FixedParent2<T>: MyProtocol {}
class FixedChild2: FixedParent2<String> {
  @objc func foo() { print("FixedChild2.foo()") }
}

(FixedChild2() as MyProtocol).foo?()
// ✅ Outputs `FixedChild2.foo()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add '@objc' to your func:

```
@objc func foo() { print("BrokenChild.foo()") }
```